# Discrete vs Continuous Replicator Dynamics

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, theoretical-biology, evolutionary-game-theory

The replicator eqn in the case of discrete non-overlapping generations and asexual reproduction is given by the **discrete** replicator eqn:
$$x_i(t+1) = x_i (t)\frac{f_i(t)}{\bar f (t)}$$
where $x_i$ is the frequency of the strategy $i$ and each individual playing strategy $i$ produces $f_i$ copies of itself in the next generation. $\bar f$ is the average fitness. Thus
\begin{equation}
\Delta x_i = x_i(t) \frac{(f_i(t) - \bar f (t))}{\bar f (t)}
\end{equation}
In the case in which $x_i$ is a continuous variable, we have the **continuous** replicator eqn given by
$$\dot x_i = x_i (f_i - \bar f)$$

**Question:** I suppose we should be able to derive the continuous replicator eqn from the discrete replicator eqn by evaluating the discrete replicator eqn for $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}$. How can I do this derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this derivation, it is better to focus on the *population size* of a strategy as opposed to the *frequency* of a strategy. Let $N_i$ be the population size of the strategy $i$. Strategies in the replicator dynamics change exponentially. The equation for continuous exponential growth is $\dot N_i = f_i N_i$. Since $x_i=N_i/N$ and $\dot N = \bar f N$, calculating $\dot x_i$ by using the quotient rule gives us the continuous replicator eqn.